# Best way to to show many dynamic filter counts in component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, methods, interpolation

I have a grid where users can add many columns and rows dynamically, then select cells in the grid.

In each column header, I want to count the number of selected cells for that column.

One way to do this is to a create a method that loops through the column count for columns i, then reference this in the component.

```
{{ getColumnSelectedCellCount(i) }}
```

The problem is that the method interpolation trigger nearly continuously, causing a drag in performance in the component.

Is there a more effective way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can use Pipes to achieve this. A pipe in angular keep a memory cache which basically say that if the arguments don't change, then we instantly return a result. So, create a `@Pipe()` and give him the right parameters

Comment: yes, call this method when you need to (when the seelction changes), and then save the result to variables, and don't rely on change detection to call it for you

Comment: @Simrugh Thanks.  Had not used a pipe for it, but that actually works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object hold table headers and count of selected cell, then update select / deselect function to update this object, and bind object values anywhere.

```
var objHeaders = { id: 0 , name: 0 }

onSelect(){
objHeaders[cellHead] += 1 ; 
}

onDeselect(){
objHeaders[cellHead] -= 1 ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

right now you're relying on change detection to call your method, instead you call it when it needs to be called and store the result in a value to interpolate...

```
columnSelectionCounts:{[colIndex:number]: number} = {};
onColumnSelectionChange(i:number) {
   this.columnSelectionCounts[i] = this.getColumnSelectedCellCount(i);
}

{{ columnSelectionCounts[i] || 0 }}
```

call that onColumnSelectionChange method whenever the selection changes for a particular column.

Comment: Thanks.  Downside of that is I also have to then keep track of columns being added / removed and add/remove that from columnSelectionCounts, as well as call onColumnSelectionChange on selections.  It works, but eventually adds up to a lot of code for a simple filter.

Comment: Presumably there’s a method called already every time something is selected or removed. You just need to be aware the changed column index and call this method with the index. Or change this method to not accept an index and recalculate all column counts every time it’s called in a loop. Either way it’s not as much effort as you’re making it out to be. Relying on change detection is a crutch